# Is the Affordable Care Act safe after the Republicans failed to repeal it?

Tags: united-states, affordable-care-act

Can the Republican Party write another bill later to try to repeal the Affordable Care Act again? Or is it here to stay?

Comment: The very fact that there's an active attempt to repeal the ACA in and of itself  (and that the folks behind that have been willing to consider efforts such as removing the incentives for healthy people to join the pools) makes the markets higher-risk to participate in than they would be otherwise. Who wants to offer a must-issue policy when for all you know six months from now your healthy clients will be able to move to something cheaper with less coverage?

Comment: ...and if the subsidies stop being paid -- which doesn't require a legislative change -- that makes a big impact on plan pricing in and of itself. Granted, though, there's (much!) more to the ACA than *just* the exchanges.

Comment: The act is safer than the actual implementation of the act.

Comment: The OP's post is ambiguous - does it mean "is the ACA here to stay" or "is the Republican Party here to stay"? Looking from the other side of the Atlantic, neither answer is obvious!

Comment: @alephzero Given recent off-cycle election results, the democrats are probably in more trouble than the republicans.

Comment: These kind of questions are slowly turning this site into Quora.

Comment: @Andy It's not that Democrats do bad in off-cycle elections.  It's that the party holding the White House does: http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2010/sep/07/mary-jordan/do-presidents-always-get-shellacked-midterm-electi/

Comment: @Andy - 538 disagrees. Basically, their verdict is "so far, emergency elections have no discernable clear signal and can be spun multiple ways - but clearly don't portend anything great for Rs"

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen Still doesn't support the notion that "republicans are in trouble."

Comment: @user4012 Eh, good for 538.  I'm sure if democrats won most of those races they'd be saying it proves republicans are in trouble too.  In the end only thing that matters is who is winning/losing elections.  Its hard to argue that republicans are in trouble when they've won more elections.

Comment: @Andy - with all due respect, I trust 538's opinion far more than random user on Internet. They've proven they generally know what they are talking about and have a track record of getting things right, especially when backed up by #s. BTW, they very explicitly covered the whole "who won matters" thing, as well.

Comment: @user4012 I really do not care who you trust.  Many people trusted polls/news predicting Clinton would win by a landslide too.  The fact is that nobody is going to be predicting with any certainty how future elections are going to shake out.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Theoretically, the Republicans can try to repeal it again, as many times and for as long as they want - or at least until they get thrown out of office by mad voters.

In practice, the longer it's around, the more political capital will be required to repeal it, and thus the less likely it'll get repealed. Republicans standing against their own camp on grounds that their own voters might lose their insurance is a telling sign that this is occurring today.

That being said, what the administration *could* also do - and in fact, [already started to do](http://money.cnn.com/2017/04/28/news/economy/obamacare-trump-100-days/index.html) - is try to sabotage it in some way or another. For instance by trying to defund it somehow, by adding a few layers of red tape, etc. The point being, if they somehow manage to set things up so the ACA is almost guaranteed to look like a failure (if only by a few criteria) a few years down the road, then they could gather enough momentum to try to repeal it again when it does. (Or maybe, as Trump tweeted, it'll implode all by itself.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63041/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-de-bernardy-is-the-affordable-care-act-safe-after).

Comment: Some additional things that make this harder for the GOP: McCain is gone until at least August, reconciliation has a no-do-overs rule, and they still have to pass a budget, continuing resolution, and/or debt-ceiling increase at some point.  All of those factors together imply formal legislative process is probably not going to happen until early-to-mid 2018 at the earliest, and by that point, midterms begin to complicate the political landscape.  Trump can do various things by himself to damage the ACA, of course, but the politics of that would be... *complicated*, to say the least.

Answer (score 13):

No, the Republicans are able to introduce further bills or amendments to repeal or replace the Affordable Care Act.

This week's vote is in fact the second attempt by Republicans at healthcare reform, after the first attempt failed in [March this year](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/24/us/politics/health-care-affordable-care-act.html) due to opposition from the Freedom Caucus.

However, President Trump is able, and has already tried, to weaken some provisions of Obamacare through executive action. [This article by The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/07/19/us/what-trump-can-do-to-let-obamacare-fail.html) shows some of the actions that Trump has taken.

Additionally, [Executive Order 13765](http://money.cnn.com/2017/04/28/news/economy/obamacare-trump-100-days/index.html), titled "Minimizing the Economic Burden of the Patient Protection and Affordable Care Act Pending Repeal", was signed by Trump on his first day in office that aimed to weaken regulations and procedures associated with Obamacare and called for its prompt repeal. The [full text can be found here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/01/2/executive-order-minimizing-economic-burden-patient-protection-and).

> It directs the secretary of health and human services, as well as other agencies, to **interpret regulations as loosely as allowed to minimize the financial burden** on individuals, insurers, health care providers and others.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Comment: Even the US military (e.g. Gen Joseph Dunford over transgender issues) is now publicly refusing to take "directions" from Trump unless they are issued as *commands*, not directions. Is the director of a civilian organization more or less likely to follow a "direction" to "interpret regulations" in a particular way than the miltary?

Comment: @alephzero: It would probably result in the IRS and others backing down from somebody wanting to bring an otherwise futile legal challenge.

Comment: @alephzero The transgender announcement was made in a tweet.  The military's position that the tweet is not a binding order is at least defensible (though I'm not sure the exact rules on this).  An executive order is unambiguously an... order.  Executive orders still have to be legal and constitutional, but I believe they're generally followed unless/until challenged successfully in court.

Answer (score 7):

No, they will be able to attempt to repeal the ACA again in the future, but it does become significantly more difficult.

What was significant about this recent vote is that they attempted to repeal it through a process known as [budget reconciliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconciliation_(United_States_Congress)). Reconciliation only requires a simple majority (50 votes) to pass and disallows filibustering, but they can only consider a reconciliation bill once per year.

To attempt to repeal the ACA now without waiting another year, the senate would need to go through the regular process to pass a bill. But that requires a supermajority (60 votes) which Republicans don't have, and any bill can be filibustered by democrats.

Comment: Not quite.  There are limits to one reconciliation bill (of each type (types are spending, revenue, and debt limit)) per budget year.  But the current bill is under this budget year, fiscal year 2017.  There is a new fiscal year (2018) starting October 1.  They may be able to pass the fiscal year 2018 reconciliation even before then, but even if they wait until October, that's not a full year.  The issue is that they wanted to use that other reconciliation bill for tax reform, so either they get health care done very soon, lose tax reform, or wait a year: https://goo.gl/3c15xt

Answer (score -1):

ACA is not 'safe' under any circumstances. It was already in trouble in its current form. [Aetna bailed](http://www.modernhealthcare.com/article/20170510/NEWS/170519969) because it was losing money on the exchanges.

[The NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/15/sunday-review/sorry-we-dont-take-obamacare.html) also chimes in with serious problems, and this was mid 2016 while the presidential campaign was well under way, with Clinton the presumptive front runner.

So the fact that the repubs couldn't agree on a replacement, and the fact that they are making the same mistake the dems made - putting together major legislation while ignoring half the country - doesn't make the current ACA 'safe'. They can try again, if they choose.

This problem won't be fixed as long as the discussion revolves around excusing one's chosen political party, while looking to slag the other. It will be solved when everyone involved makes solving the problem the main priority, regardless of who gets flamed or who gets the credit.

The chances of that happening are not good. The majority of politicians, and a good deal of citizens, are too focused on a partisan battle that no one can win.

Comment: The reason for a lot of the withdrawals from the market is due to the uncertainty with Trump and the GOP. When there's no longer a guarantee of continuity, there's no compelling reason for the insurance company to gamble. So it's not entirely fair to say it was "in trouble" to the same extent pre Trump.

Comment: That said, despite any inherent problems the ACA had, it wasn't going to just disappear. It was law and policy so it would have always come down to congress to act upon it one way or the other. Finally, I think it's also unfair to say "a majority of politicians" want a partisan battle. The ACA *was* a plan. The GOP congress never *had* a plan. So at least half the politicians at least *tried* to solve a problem (ironically, based off of a plan from a member of the "other team")

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, it appears to me that ACA is failing on its own. Actually, when it was passed it was tremendously flawed and because of the lack of any bipartisan support, wasn't corrected before (as well as after) it went into effect. It has been withering on the vine since Obama signed it into law. The enormous price hikes and Insurer's withdrawals from the market are both signs of serious (and I expect, fatal) problems. All Trump needs to do is to direct the IRS and the DOJ not to enforce the requirement for all to be insured. I'm not clear how easily this can be done, the IRS doesn't appear to have done much to sabotage it, so far... To answer your question: I think that the Legislative Branch is going to have to eventually either drastically change it or replace it in the not too distant future. I'd guess by 2023 or 4.

Comment: Hi and welcome. To make this a better answer please support it with evidence rather than your opinion. Citing the serious signs would be an easy start, and I'm pretty sure others have opined similarly, linking to them would lend support.

Comment: +1 For obamacare dying on its own, see http://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/27/more-americans-will-be-without-obamacare-insurance-options-next-year.html

Comment: @mj_ I'm not sure that's evidence of "dying on its own", given that insurers have expressed significant frustration with having to set rates before knowing if the rules will be changed afterwards. Some of the big premium hikes next year are to account for the worst-case scenarios like subsidies not being paid. There are a lot of things Trump can do (and is doing) to *help* it collapse.

Comment: The issues you point out (insurer withdrawals) have more to do with Trump than Obamacare. Had Obamacare continued on being fully supported, things would have continued on as planned. The insurers withdrawing has everything to do with the chaos that is this GOP congress.

Comment: @ceejayoz obamacare in itself was never sustainable. the fact that trump removed subsidies only highlights the precarious nature of the plan. read this http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2017-11-17/helpless-raging-charlottesville-families-shocked-these-2018-obamacare-premiumsits-ho

Comment: @mj_ Yeah, gonna need a better source than a Zero Hedge editorial by "Tyler Durden". "Zero Hedge's content has been classified as 'alt-right', anti-establishment, conspiratorial, and economically pessimistic, and has been criticized for presenting extreme and sometimes pro-Russian views." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Hedge

Comment: @ceejayoz, the reference in the ZeroHedge article goes to the Washington Post. ZeroHedge has a tremendous advantage in that it follows the money, something other media tend to ignore because their ideologies are more important. They, and the establishment by extension, instead present "hope" as a plan which in reality never pans out the way you want it to. Regarding the pro-Russian views, no matter what you or I think about the Russians, that doesn't mean that they don't have positive characteristics.